# `usermod: user 'mahmoud' does not exist dpkg: error processing kismet (--configure)` error when installing kismet

Tags: apt, dpkg, software-installation

I am kind of new to Ubuntu, and I had nothing wrong until I upgraded my system to Ubuntu 13.10. While the upgrading process I got an error message that `kismet` can not be downloaded, and when I figured out that it is a sniffing tool I thought that I will not need it anyway.

But after installing `gpointing-device-settings` and some other softwares; I get this error shown below; I have my software installed but I just want to understand why I get this error; why it is related to kismet and do I need to install `kismet` ?!

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gpointing-device-settings is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libaccounts-qt5-1 libc-ares2 libdee-qt5-3 libllvm3.1:i386
  libqt5graphicaleffects5 libqt5network5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5svg5
  libqt5v8-5 libqt5xml5 libsignon-qt5-1 libsmi2ldbl libwireshark-data
  libwireshark2 libwiretap2 libwsutil2 linux-headers-3.5.0-17
  linux-headers-3.5.0-18 linux-headers-3.5.0-18-generic
  qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin qtdeclarative5-friends-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin
  ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme wireshark wireshark-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up kismet (2011.03.R2-2) ...
usermod: user 'mahmoud' does not exist
dpkg: error processing kismet (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 6
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 kismet
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations, you found your first bug. Now to workaround you need to create the user yourself:

```
sudo adduser mahmoud
```

Now uninstall kismet:

```
sudo apt-get purge kismet
```

Now clean your system:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: It seems to work.I don't get the error msg anymore...Thanks so much :)